# Providing restricted access with ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Can we allow ContentProvider of one application to be accessed by other applications, but they can only access some part of the data which the providing application wants to be public.

In other words is it the case that ContentProvider either gives complete access to data or none. If not how?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a bit on how you want the other applications to access data in the `ContentProvider`.

If you want third-party applications to be able to retrieve data from your provider at any point in time, for any reason, then the normal behavior is to allow them access to everything in that provider, so long as they hold the right permissions. You can require the third-party app to hold certain permissions to read and/or write data in your provider. It is theoretically possible to use `Binder.getCallingUid()` to try to determine the app that is trying to work with your provider, and somehow restrict access based on who the requester is, but I have not tried this, and it may not be practical in any case.

If, however, you want third-party applications to retrieve data from your provider *only when you ask them to* -- typically by launching one of their activities -- you can limit the scope of access to a single `Uri`. This would be the pattern that an email client would use, for example. Some emails have attachments, which the email client would want to open up for viewing in some other app (e.g., PDF attachment in a PDF viewer). The email client would serve up the attachments via a `ContentProvider`, but not allow arbitrary access (`android:exported="false"`). Then, they would use flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_GRANT_READ_PERMISSION` on the `Intent` used to start the third-party app to signify that the `Uri` in the `Intent` can be used by the third-party app to retrieve data from the provider.

Comment: My question is whether an application can be able to restrict access to some subdata (say pictures) while allowing to access other subdata(contacts, videos) through ContentProvider.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: IMHO, you are better served creating separate providers.